# Windows desktop multi-touch trackpad/touchpad?

Tags: windows, touchpad

I love the MacBook Trackpad and it's gestures, and I would like something like it that is compatible for Windows. I know Apple actually sells its Magic Trackpad, but the problem is that there are no actual multi-touch gestures supported, even with third party applications.

So to the point: Is there an external trackpad/touchpad for Windows devices with nice multi-touch gestures?

Example Gestures:

- 3 Fingers swiped upwards: Overview of all present windows and desktops
- 4 fingers "pinched": making desktop free; Pulling the 4 fingers back together puts windows back on screen
- 3 Finger swiped horizontally: Switching between desktops

Budget is actually not that much of a problem. I'm ready to pay a few bucks for decent hardware. Since Apple sells its newest Trackpad "Magic Trackpad 2" for 149.99 €, I think that might be a fair price for a decent Windows Trackpad

Comment: Can you describe some of the "nice gestures" you are wanting in a track pad? Do you have a budget for this device?

Comment: have you used your favorite search engine to search for "touchpad for windows"? When I did, there were many many results, too many to list.

Comment: @Cfinley I've added some example gestures. Windows (10) has those features actually built in and I know some Laptops do support gestures like that, but I don't know any external trackpads for desktop use.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I (of course) actually did that. When I did this, I found like 99% articles about how to configure your laptop trackpack properly and 1% were 2 old Logitech Trackpads, not being supported by windows later than 7 and a Lenovo Trackpad, not being supported by windows later than 7. Of course, one can buy the Magic Trackpad from Apple (which I honestly considered), but this doesn't support multi touch gestures on Windows 10, too, afaik.

Comment: Are you looking for one that you can configure yourself or a Windows Precision trackpad that supports [the default Microsoft gestures?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17206/windows-10-try-touchpad-gestures) Both solutions will fulfill your requirements, but are vastly different methods of doing it.

Comment: @JMY1000 I just ordered [this Touchpad from JellyComb](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06XGB8MN2) (Which is available in my country). I found this during to your comment about "Windows Precision Trackpads". I did not know, there was a standard like that. Thanks a lot! Even though that Touchpad looks poorly (at least on pictures), I will try, how it works. Actually seems to be the only external touchpad with officially support for precision gestures.

I actually do not mind the way of fulfilling my requirements, so Precision Gestures might be just fine.

Comment: @JMY1000 I tested the Touchpad from JellyComb and a Logitech T650, I could borrow from a colleague for a little time. Both aren't as good as the gesture control, known from Apple. In the end, the T650 feels a lot better than the JellyComb, but unfortunately it suffers from bad software support by Logitech. In the end I decided to use the JellyComb Touchpad, because it integrates better with Win10. 
I'd say, a well made Touchpad with good configurable software would be a lot better than the JellyComb, but the Precise Gestures deliver a pretty good (standardized) experience so far.

Comment: @epilepticz Quick question: are you using this trackpad with another computer, or are you using it with a Mac? If so, what Mac?

Comment: @JMY1000 I'm using it with my Windows 10 Computer in office only. I can try it out on my Mac on monday, too, if you want me to.

Comment: @epilepticz There are some third party drivers for the Magic Trackpad 2 that can be used, but given the price of the Magic Trackpad 2, I'd vote for something else. I'm going to do some more research then post an answer.